# Working on a poster wanting to put an image and a table side by side

Tags: graphics, align

Hi all I am sorry I am new here, still struggle even imputing the question I apologize.
What I have is an image and a table inside a mini page of a poster that I want to put side by side but I cannot. I would appreciate some help.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox2] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{13in}
\[\]
\fontsize{28pt}{24pt}\selectfont{

%\[\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{cg1}
\label{fu}
\end{figure}

\begin{minipage}{4in}   
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||c|c||} 
 \hline
 d & ML Degree \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 3 & 2 \\ 
 \hline
 4 & 8  \\
 \hline
 5 & 22  \\
 \hline
 6 & 52  \\
 \hline
 7 & 118 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please add to your code `documentclass`. Probably in poster the float environments aren't feasible ... Probably removing empty lines between minipages will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question is quit common on SE, so it is probably duplicate, but anyway since I didn't check this ...

Your MWE is not complete and have some spurious code, so the answer below is based on guessing. In it I use `article` for document class, but I'm sure that convert basic idea in MWE to your `poster` class should be straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc,caption}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-2.2in}
    \centering
\captionof{figure}{}    \label{fig:fu}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in} 
    \centering  
\captionof{table}{}  \label{fu}
    \begin{tabular}{||c|c||}
        \hline
d & ML Degree   \\ 
                    \hline\hline
3 & 2           \\  \hline
4 & 8           \\  \hline
5 & 22          \\  \hline
6 & 52          \\  \hline
7 & 118         \\  \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]